# In-line visualization of content age

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have two tables, pages and revisions. Revisions has a foreign key to a page. The contents of a page is the latest entry in the revisions table for that page. The revisions are full copies of the contents, no deltas.

As an experiment, I would like to visualize the revision state of the current revision. If text is new in the current revision, don't do anything. If it is from a recent revision, give it a green background color. If it's very old, give it a red background color. In between, orange. A heat map diff of the age of the content, so to speak.

My question is: **How I can extract this data from the revisions of a page?** Pointers to literature would be equally useful to actual code solving this problem.

Not really relevant, but just in case: It's for a Ruby project, Ruby on Rails in fact. [Here's the project, on github](http://github.com/augustl/kii).

Update: here's an example test case, written in Ruby. http://pastie.org/631604

Comment: So basically you want to be able to track the age of different parts of text in a record field?

Comment: Or are you tracking the age of multiple revisions that are all put together to form the current page?

Comment: Since I'm not storing deltas, I _think_ the answers are yes and no respectively. I want to track revisions older that the current revision (doesn't have to be the most recent revision, but that's irrelevant, I guess), which is the only possible source of the content since the content of a revision can't include anything of the content in revisions newer than itself.

Comment: Sheesh. That's a toughy. Why not just store deltas?

Comment: Would it be easier if deltas were stored? I don't know much about how deltas work, but I could just as well create deltas from all the none-delta revisions and then work with that, right?

Comment: Yea. Maybe look for a preferred differential algorithm that can determine the difference between two revisions. Then you basically stack that algorithm across all the revisions and color code the text based on the revision date?

Comment: In the test case assert, did you mean: `assert_equal expected, visualizer.nodes`?

Comment: I've integrated my LCS code with your test case which now passes. See the revised answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update*:
  [ long and slightly off-topic answer on longest-common-subsequence deleted ]

I've integrated my Hunt-McIlroy Algorithm subsequence finder with your test case, which now passes. I made various mods to your test case, see it [here at pastie.org.](http://pastie.org/656850) Likewise, [here is the rdiff module](http://pastie.org/656869). Here is my svn log for why your [test case was changed.](http://pastie.org/656853)

Comment: I have experimented with the `Diff::LCS` gem as well, to get the diffs between the various revisions. What I haven't figured out is a way to use the diffs, though. I guess the output of your LCS class is similar to the output of the `Diff::LCS` gem?

Comment: Oh, heh, I didn't know about that. It looks like we have done something similar. I would have extended my results to your nicely written test case if I had more time, but I started on this question just a few hours before the deadline.

Comment: I guess you could always ask another question... :-)

Comment: Super-awesome! Going afk for a few days, I'll take a look at this when I get back. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One quick way to do it is to get the successive versions of the page and run them through the [diff](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff) utility to get deltas, so you know what to color how. You could of course reinvent the code that goes from two complete pages and finds which bits they have in common, but it's going to be faster to reuse existing code.

Comment: How would you pass something to `diff` that isn't stored as files? The revisions comes from the DB, and afaik `diff` can't take input from STDIN.

Comment: Hi, I think you could work with temporal files (the *diff* command inputs)

Comment: Ah, so I would have to create tempfiles. How can I use diffs to visualize the content age, though?

Answer (score 2):

You can use svn blame command to gain similar results. Of course revisions and pages needs to be stored in svn. If migrating to svn is a roadblock, maybe examining svn sources how blame command is written might help.

**Edit: @August** 
*In order to visualize this, I need something that doesn't care about lines. Don't I?*

Well, you need blame for rows and diff for contents of single row. The first one is performed by VCS, second one you can do by yourself or third party code. For every change store in database deltas of blame commends (only changed rows need to be saved). In sample results for one row we have:

```
Rev. num.    Value
      23     Hello worl
      36     Hello cruel world
      45     Hello wonderful world
```

The desired for you result I assume is (for clarity I've skiped white spaces)
Afer first diff:

```
(Hello)(23)(cruel)(36)(worl)(23)(d)(36)
```

After second diff:

```
(Hello)(23)(wonderful)(45)(worl)(23)(d)(36)
```

Unified diff doesn't help in this case, so diff need to be done otherwise. You can write algoritm for diff yourself or find appropiate code in merge tools. Below is example of how TortiseMerge does the stuff.

[tortise merge http://img169.imageshack.us/img169/7871/merge.png](http://img169.imageshack.us/img169/7871/merge.png)

The problem isn't simple one but I think that my ideas might help you a little or give any clues.

Comment: Good idea, but I'd rather store it in a DB so that scaling the system is easier.

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that storing the data in a DB would be appreciably more scalable than storing it in any reasonable VCS; this is the sort of work they are specifically designed to handle, whereas a relational (I'm assuming) DB is designed to support ad-hoc querying, etc.

A more likely source of problems would be integrating the DB-backed part of the app with the part that talks to the VCS. For ideas of how to manage that, you could look at projects like django-vcs http://code.google.com/p/django-vcs/

Comment: Can svn/git/[other vcs] help me visualizing the content age, though?

Comment: Yes. Output of svn blame command is simple to parse and you have all data you need (revision and content).

Comment: Isn't `svn blame` a per-line kind of thing, similar to `git blame`? In order to visualize this, I need something that doesn't care about lines. Don't I?

Answer (score 2):

One thing. Heat implies activity or energy, so I would flip your colors around so that
the most recent are red (hot) and the older text is blue/green (cooled off).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any DVCS to achieve that. I'd recommend git. It will be even better than using db.

Comment: Got any examples on how I could use Git to do this? I can't store the content in git, has to be stored in a DB. I could pass content to git, though.

Comment: You can just store both in db and git. DB will contain latest revision of the text. In git you can store file with ID from db for example, and everytime time you overwrite it issue git commit.
This way you'll be able to get history/diff of every file and even line in the file.

Comment: I can't think of any git commands that visualize the content age, though. Can git actually do this?